# Converting to money format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following query trying to apply money format.

```
  select case when c.num is null 
              then 0.00 
              else '$' + Convert(varchar,CONVERT(money(c.total+c.customerS),1),2)
         end verified
  from table_Sales c
  where c.id=@id
```

When I run this it gives error it couldn't convert varchar to numeric. When i change 
varchar to integer or numeric it doesn't do anything.

Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: Also, change `..Convert(varchar,..` to something like `..Convert(varchar(100),..`

Comment: What is `ts.id`. There is no `ts` table in your query.

Comment: Why not stored it in Decimal(10,2) datatype? insted of money ?

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi you mean instead of varchar or money type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both types in Case Clause must be same, so `0.00` must be `'0.00'`

Query:

```
select case when c.num is null 
              then '0.00' 
              else '$' + Convert(varchar,CONVERT(money(c.total+c.customerS),1),2)
         end verified
  from table_Sales c
  where c.id=@id
```

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I appreciate this is not a direct answer, I would strongly advocate NOT formatting numeric data to strings in the data layer.

It feels to me a lot more like the type of logic which would or could be application specific. What if you want to re-use the same query to work with GBP or Euros?

Additionally, what if your application needs to handle more than one currency?

I would suggest returning the data without the addition of the currency symbol in decimal form and applying the formatting within the application or on the client side if web based maybe.

Just my 2c(or 2p)